# Why isn't this texture loading properly on a sphere object? VISUAL STUDIO

Tags: c++, visual-studio, graphics

I am recreating the planet Earth on Visual Studio 19, but the texture isn't adding good to the sphere.

**THIS IS HOW I LOAD THE IMAGE**

[image]

**THIS IS HOW IT'S DISPLAYED**

[image]

**THIS IS THE FRAGMENT SHADER FOR THE PLANET**

[image]

Why isn't this looking realistic as it should be?

I am new on this type of programming so if I missed any crucial code fragment, ask and I will edit this with it.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Also, where is the actual rendering and model setup code? Have you tried rendering the texture coordinates as the fragment color to see if they match your intent? If you map the texture (u, v) to the color (u, v, 0) one pole should be dark green, moving to yellow at the other pole.

Comment: Are you sure the UVs are correct?